# Get rid of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, uniq, group

There is an array for each id key that is not needed. That is kind of a group break.

```
const header = [
[
{ id: "1",
   text: "A",
},
],
[
{ id: "2",
  text: "B",
  array:[1,2,3],
},
{ id: "2",
  text: "B1",
},
],
[
{ id: "3",
  text: "A",
},
],
];
```

The result should be that below. The array between the same id should disapear. Only one array that contains the data as objects should remain.

```
const header = [
{ id: "1",
  text: "A",
},
{ id: "2",
  text: "B",
  array:[1,2,3],
},
{ id: "2",
   text: "B1",
},
{ id: "3",
   text: "A",
},
];
```

Comment: From where is coming this array? Database (if yes how?)? From a javascirpt function?...

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to archive is called flatten.
JavaScript has the build in method to archive this: `Array.prototype.flat()`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Example (taken from the source above)

```js
const arr1 = [0, 1, 2, [3, 4]];

console.log(arr1.flat());
// expected output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

const arr2 = [0, 1, 2, [[[3, 4]]]];
console.log(arr2.flat(2));
// expected output: [0, 1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use nested loops, since every index of an array is also an array and push items in an new array.

```
const header = [
    [{ id: '1', text: 'A' }],
    [
        { id: '2', text: 'B', array: [1, 2, 3] },
        { id: '2', text: 'B1' },
    ],
    [{ id: '3', text: 'A' }],
];

const newHeader = [];
header.forEach(headerItems => {
    headerItems.forEach(headerItem => {
       newHeader.push(headerItem)
    });
})

console.log(newHeader);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using flat() method.

This link is related about flat method : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

This is my code :

```js
// before
const header = [
    [{ id: '1', text: 'A' }],
    [
        { id: '2', text: 'B', array: [1, 2, 3] },
        { id: '2', text: 'B1' }
    ],
    [{ id: '3', text: 'A' }]
]

// expected output
const headerFlat = [
    { id: '1', text: 'A' },
    { id: '2', text: 'B', array: [1, 2, 3] },
    { id: '2', text: 'B1' },
    { id: '3', text: 'A' }
]

// using flat()
const flat = header.flat()
console.log(flat)
```